# Cross Site Scripting Iframe Permission Denied issue

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe, cross-domain

I am getting Cross Site Scripting error on the following code.

**Javascript**

```
 function resizeIframe(ifRef) 
            {
                var ifDoc;
                //alert(ifRef);

                try
                { 
                    ifDoc = ifRef.contentWindow.document.documentElement; 
                }
                catch( e )
                {
                   alert(e);
                    try
                    { 
                    ifDoc = ifRef.contentDocument.documentElement; 
                    }
                    catch( ee ){
                             alert(ee);
                          } 
                }
                //var doc = ifRef.height;
                //alert(doc);
                if(ifDoc)
                {
                    ifRef.height = 1; 
                    ifRef.style.height = ifDoc.scrollHeight+'px';               
                }
            }
```

**Iframe**

```
<iframe onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="margin-bottom: 16px;" src="ourteamnav/first.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="597" height="240"></iframe>
```

The Errors are following

**For 'e' :**

Mozilla Firefox : **Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'**

Google Chrome :  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined**

Internet Explorer : **TypeError: Permission denied**

**And for 'ee' :**

Mozilla Firefox : **Error: Permission denied to access property 'documentElement'**

Google Chrome :  **TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null**

Internet Explorer : **Error: Access is denied.**

I think it can not be solved in general way as it s happening because of domain is pointing another domain. So will anyone guide me to solve it without using these property of Javascript `contentDocument.documentElement` or `contentWindow.document.documentElement` for re-sizing the Iframe Content dynamically according to its inner Content.

Thanks

Comment: just checking: are these different domains, or different sub-domains within a same domain?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer of [Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485406/christophe), I wanted to point out (sadly) `postMessage` doesn't work on all browsers.

Luckily, [Josh Fraser](http://www.onlineaspect.com/about/) already provided [**a backwards compatible version of window.postMessage()**](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/). It checks if the browser supports the `postMessage`-method. If it does, it uses that. If not, it uses the **URL** (both from the iframe and the parent) to pass along data.

Now you can use the following methods to let both windows "talk" to eachother:

```
XD.postMessage(msg, src, frames[0]);
XD.receiveMessage(function(message){
    window.alert(message.data + " received on "+window.location.host);
}, 'URL');
```

Just make sure you read the documentation properly, since the configuration has to be set just right.

Comment: OMG. I am confused again. Now raising my hand

Comment: Don't need to; this solution is just an addition to the list Christophe already posted (make sure you check the browser compatibility). Pick one that works for you and go with it (this XD-version worked for me, but I'm sure there are many out there).

Comment: +1 for the url technique. @Soumya there are several workarounds, if you need to support older browsers you're better off using a library that already has all figured out.

Comment: Thanks to you both very much. Thought I didn't succeeded yet but I will let you know if I would.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, this is a cross-domain issue.

If you have control on both pages you can use postMessage to exchange information between the two pages.

Some references:

- [Ben Alman's example of resizing iframes](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/examples/iframe/)
- [John Resig's article](http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/) on postMessaging
- [this excellent presentation](http://benvinegar.github.com/seamless-talk/#/) on iframes (what you're
  interested in starts at [slide 16](http://benvinegar.github.com/seamless-talk/#/16)).
- [a list of libraries/plugins](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) that include this technique

Comment: Really Thanks for that. I went through it but somehow confused how to implement it.

Comment: I have added more references, hope this helps. You can also google for "iframe resize postMessage"

Comment: I got some but it seems to HTML 5 content. I don't know if this will run on IE8

Comment: @Soumya added a list of libraries that should take care of older IE

Comment: @Christophe: And if I don't have a control over the iframe content (which is loaded from another domain), how can I modify it's HTML?

Comment: @dma_k you just can't.