# I want to run remote code in another tab?

Tags: javascript, function, promise, window.open

I want to run remote code in another tab (using delay).

Code:

```js
var win = window.open('https://www.google.com');
win.test = function () {
    win.alert("Starting magic...");

}
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
win.test()
```

return `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Permission denied to access property "test" on cross-origin object`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have control over both of the websites?

Comment: "Permission denied to run arbitrary code on google.com" seems pretty reasonable to me. I would not want to grant that permission to an arbitrary website.

Comment: This question might be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044292/cross-site-scripting-iframe-permission-denied-issue

Comment: Just the first sentence of "I want to run remote code in another tab" makes me feel dirty. Just sayin.

Comment: If you're just trying to get a process to run outside of the current tab, you could look at service workers. If you're trying to inject code on google, good luck.